# Akka with Xamarin Error "Configuration system failed initialize"

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019, akka.net

Hello I am trying execute a xamarin app and I would like to create an actor, through the actor system of the akka library, but I receive the error “Configuration system failed initialize” just when trying to create the ActorSystem.

```
         private static readonly ActorSystem _system;
         public static readonly IActorRef _coordinator;

         static CrawlingSystem ()
         {
             _system = ActorSystem.Create ("crawling-system");
             _coordinator = _system.ActorOf (Props.Create <BackupActor> (), "backupactor");
         }
```

The static CreawlingSystem class is called directly by MainPage.Xaml.cs

I am using visual Studio 2019, an empty Xamarin.Forms project, akka 1.4.21, Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2012.

Also i tried with versions: akka 1.3.9, Xamarin.Forms 3.3.0912540, but the error persists

Comment: Can you include the full type of the exception that was raised here? I think this might be an issue with `System.Configuration` dependencies being brought in and invoked during the `ActorSystem.Create` call

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `ActorSystem.Create` call to the following:

```
 _system = ActorSystem.Create ("crawling-system", ""); // empty config
```

This will stop Akka.NET from trying to query against `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`, which is apparently not supported on Xamarin and gets loaded automatically when no default configuration is provided.